# $x_0$ in Newton-Raphson method for reciprocal square root for floating-point arithmetic

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, approximation

How to choose $x_0$ expressed as $(1+f)2^p$ in Newton-Raphson method for reciprocal square root to be close enough to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$? Starting with: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+f)2^p}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+f)}}2^{\frac{-p}{2}}$ what to do with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+f)}}$?

Comment: First of all, *Welcome to the site !*. At least to me, it is not very clear. Do you want to solve $x^2=\frac 1a$ and choose the best $x_0$ written as $x_0=(1+f)^{2p}$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I think he's angling for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root

Comment: @user5713492. Thanks for  the link ! I did not know this approach. Cheers :-)

Comment: You would have to test it, any preparation contributes cycles for usually relatively small accuracy gain. Simplest to set the mantissa to 1, that is, $x_0=2^{-p}$ if $\frac12\le 4^{-p}a\le 2$. Use more complicated initial points only if the procedure gives an extra-ordinary gain in accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

There is a trick that works with IEEE-$754$ floating point numbers where the high bit is the sign bit, the next bits are the biased exponent, and the low bits are the bits of the mantissa with a leading $1$ bit implicit. Thus a single precision number would we
$$x=(-1)^{b_{31}}2^{b_{23}:b_{30}-127}\left(1+\frac{b_0:b_{22}}{2^{23}}\right)$$
For numbers you can take the square root of, $b_{31}=0$. The trick is to interpret the bits of the floating point number as an integer, subtract this integer from a magic number, then shift the bits of the result right by one position and interpret the resulting bucket of bits as a floating point number.

Just considering what this does to the exponent, the subtraction negates the exponent, producing the reciprocal and the right shift, which is a division by $2$, yields the square root. Multiplying the input by $4$ will divide the output by $2$ so we only have to consider inputs $1\le x\le4$. Our function will be continuous (neglecting the discrete nature of computer arithmetic) and linear except for kink points where the slope changes where the input or output is exactly a power of $2$. Thus we have kink points for $x\in\{1,2,4,x_0\}$ with $2$ cases:
**Case $1$**: $1<x_0<2$, $y(x_0)=1$. Then the biased exponent for input and output is $127$ and bits $b_0:b_{22}=(x_0-1)\cdot2^{23}$. So
$$\left(\text{magic}-\left(127+x_0-1\right)\cdot2^{23}\right)/2=127\cdot2^{23}$$
So
$$\text{magic}=\left(381+(x_0-1)\right)\cdot2^{23}$$
Evaluating at the kink points:
$$\begin{align}n(1)&=\left(381+(x_0-1)-127\right)\cdot2^{23}/2=\left(127+\frac{x_0-1}2\right)\cdot2^{23}\\
y(1)&=(1)\left(1+\frac{x_0-1}2\right)=\frac{x_0+1}2\\
y(x_0)&=1\\
n(2)&=(381+(x_0-1)-128)\cdot2^{23}/2=\left(126+\frac12+\frac{x_0-1}2\right)\cdot2^{23}\\
y(2)&=\left(\frac12\right)\left(1+\frac{x_0}2\right)=\frac{x_0+2}4\\
n(4)&=(381+(x_0-1)-129)\cdot2^{23}/2=\left(126+\frac{x_0-1}2\right)\cdot2^{23}\\
y(4)&=\left(\frac12\right)\left(1+\frac{x_0-1}2\right)=\frac{x_0+1}4\end{align}$$
**Case $2$**: $2<x_0<4$, $y(x_0)=\frac12$. Then the biased exponent is $128$ for input and $126$ for output and bit $b_0:b_{22}=\left(\frac12x_0-1\right)\cdot2^{23}$. So
$$\left(\text{magic}-\left(128+\frac12x_0-1\right)\cdot2^{23}\right)/2=126\cdot2^{23}$$
So
$$\text{magic}=\left(380+\frac{x_0-2}2\right)\cdot2^{23}$$
Evaluating at the kink points:
$$\begin{align}n(1)&=\left(380+\frac{x_0-2}2-127\right)\cdot2^{23}/2=\left(126+\frac12+\frac{x_0-2}4\right)\cdot2^{23}\\
y(1)&=\left(\frac12\right)\left(1+\frac{x_0}4\right)=\frac{x_0+4}8\\
n(2)&=\left(380+\frac{x_0-2}2-128\right)\cdot2^{23}/2=\left(126+\frac{x_0-2}4\right)\cdot2^{23}\\
y(2)&=\left(\frac12\right)\left(1+\frac{x_0-2}4\right)=\frac{x_0+2}8\\
y(x_0)&=\frac12\\
n(4)&=\left(380+\frac{x_0-2}2-129\right)\cdot2^{23}/2=\left(125+\frac12+\frac{x_0-2}4\right)\cdot2^{23}\\
y(4)&=\left(\frac14\right)\left(1+\frac{x_0}4\right)=\frac{x_0+4}{16}\end{align}$$
Filling in the linear regions between the kink points we get a graph like this:
[image: Fig. 1]

We can see that Case $2$ is better.

Newton's iteration for $1/\sqrt D$ is
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{D-\frac1{x_n^2}}{\frac2{x_n^3}}=\frac32x_n-\frac12Dx_n^3$$
If $x_n=r+e_n$ where $r^2D=1$ then
$$r+e_{n+1}=\frac32(r+e_n)-\frac12D(r+e_n)^3=r-\frac32\sqrt De_n^2-\frac12De_n^3$$
So the absolute error propagates like
$$e_{n+1}=-\frac32\sqrt De_n^2-\frac12De_n^3$$
And the relative error is $\epsilon_n=e_n\sqrt D$ so
$$\epsilon_{n+1}=-\frac32\epsilon_n^2-\frac32\epsilon_n^3$$
We can plot this:
[image: fig 2]
Then we can see that the worst errors are at the minimum near $D=2.5766$ and the kink point where $D=x_0$. The least error happens when those two values are the same which happens near $x_0=3.7298003391605700$ so
$$\text{magic}=\left(380+\frac{x_0-2}2\right)\cdot2^{23}=3194926348=\text{BE6EB50C}$$
in hex. In double precision this would be
$$\text{magic}=\left(3068+\frac{x_0-2}2\right)\cdot2^{52}=13820938820854116179=\text{BFCDD6A18F6A6F53}$$
in hex.

**EDIT**: I have seen an analysis somewhere that leads to a sixth-degree equation for $x_0$. It goes something like this: if in the first graph above we shifted the kink point $x_0$ to the left it would increase $|\epsilon_0(x_0)|$ hence $|\epsilon_1(x_0)|$ while if we shifted $x_0$ to the right it would increase $|\epsilon_0(x)|$ and $|\epsilon_1(x)|$ so the best approximation happens when
$$\begin{align}\epsilon_1(x)-\epsilon_1(x_0)&=-\frac32\epsilon_0(x)^2-\frac12\epsilon_0(x)^3+\frac32\epsilon_0(x_0)^2+\frac12\epsilon_0(x_0)^3\\
&=\left(\epsilon_0(x_0)-\epsilon_0(x)\right)\left(\frac32\epsilon_0(x)+\frac32\epsilon_0(x_0)+\frac12\epsilon_0(x)^2+\frac12\epsilon_0(x)\epsilon_0(x_0)+\frac12\epsilon_0(x_0)^2)\right)\\
&=0\end{align}$$
The first factor above can't be $0$ because $\epsilon_0(x_0)<0<\epsilon_0(x)$ and
$$\epsilon_0(x)=y(x)\sqrt x-1=\left(-\frac18x+\frac{x_0+4}8\right)\sqrt x-1=-\frac18x^{3/2}+\frac{x_0+4}8x^{1/2}-1$$
And
$$\epsilon_0(x_0)=y(x_0)\sqrt{x_0}-1=\frac12\sqrt{x_0}-1$$
The second factor above thus reads
$$\frac1{128}x^3-\frac{x_0+4}{64}x^2-\frac1{32}\sqrt{x_0}x^{3/2}+\frac{(x_0+4)^2}{128}x+\frac{x_0+4}{32}\sqrt{x_0}x^{1/2}+\frac18x_0-\frac32=0$$
$\epsilon_1(x)$ was a local minimum so $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ of the above must also be $0$:
$$\begin{align}&\frac3{128}x^2-\frac{x_0+4}{32}x-\frac3{64}\sqrt{x_0}x^{1/2}+\frac{(x_0+4)^2}{128}+\frac{x_0+4}{64}\sqrt{x_0}x^{-1/2}\\
&\quad=\frac3{128x^{1/2}}\left(x^{3/2}-(x_0+4)x^{1/2}-2\sqrt{x_0}\right)\left(x-\frac{x_0+4}3\right)=0\end{align}$$
The middle factor is negative because $x<x_0$, so $x=\frac{x_0+4}3$. Sustituting into the previous equation we get
$$\frac1{128}\left(\frac4{27}(x_0+4)^3+16x_0-
192+\frac83(x_0+4)\left(\frac{x_0+4}3\right)^{1/2}\sqrt{x_0}\right)=0$$
Rearranging and squaring we get
$$(x_0^3+12x_0^2+156x_0-1232)^2=108x_0(x_0+4)^3$$
And this finally simplifies to the famous sixth degree equation
$$x_0^6+24x_0^5+348x_0^4-16x_0^3-10416x_0^2-391296x_0+1517824=0$$
For the kink point. The only feasible real solution $x_0\in(2,4)$ is
$$x_0\approx3.729800339160570568715131749987185867445$$